# how to redirect spring security to custom login page in spring-boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am creating a spring boot application. I want to add custom login page into it. How do i do that?
I am attaching my structure just for reference.
[my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thTrj.png)

Comment: Please read the manuals https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I read that and i have also created something like that but my application is not reaching at login.jsp page can you look into it?[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417931/cant-map-to-custom-login-url-in-spring-security-using-spring-boot]

Comment: Move your page_login.jsp in the views directory

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I am still not able to reach there i moved that file in views directory.

Comment: this is the problem i am getting in m y console WARN 697 --- [nio-8181-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/page-login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Comment: @SimonMartinelli and it was working fine before enabling spring security.

Comment: The code is wrong where your comment is: "I don't know why i have done this" Please read the docs

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i referred the docs and changed my code at that particular line. it is still not working can you please check and help me? thank you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417931/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-login-in-dispatcherservlet-with-na

Comment: The easiest way to help you is when you create a project on https://github.com/ and and push your source code.

Comment: how about remote access? Can you do it? if you have time. sorry if i am asking too much thank you.@SimonMartinelli

Comment: I've got the solution.security was preventing application.properties to read so i override those properties and now it is working fine.@SimonMartinelli.Thank you for your guidance

Comment: I'm happy that you solved the problem. Can you add the solution as the answer, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By applying spring security If application.properties does't work you can apply the

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
InternalResourceViewResolver resolver= new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

method it will work.